# What kind of genetic mutation would make a woman produce more testosterone than a man?

Tags: biology, medicine

Considering that in my story the woman has a XX cariotype( not AIS) and has PCOS or other condition that make her body produce a lot of androgens. I know that some conditions can make the adrenal glands produce too much testosterone and I had read that androstenedione can be converted into testosterone and estrogen can turn into testosterone as well.

But how could she produce that much testosterone 10x higher than average with a female normal cariotype and normal female internal sex organs?

Comment: Same question?  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/188677/is-there-a-real-life-intersex-condition-that-leads-to-functioning-ovaries-but-wi/188680#188680

Comment: The [tag:reality-check] tag is ***NOT*** for asking "can X happen?" type questions. It's purpose (explained in the [help/on-topic] and on the tag's wiki page) is for ***you*** to provide ***both*** the relevant rules of your world ***and*** the circumstance, application, or consideration to be tested so that we can determine if your world's rules are being consistently used. Despite the question being closed, I've removed the tag as inappropriately used.